# JQuery Mobile,Fixed toolbar is not working

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am viewing [this](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html) demo page in my IPhone but it seems fixed toolbar is not working. I can see fixed toolbars when viewed in firefox in normal browser but in mobile browser on IPhone these toolbars are not fixed and they scroll when page is scrolled.

Comment: It does not work, even on Firefox, when you touch/click the page. Have look at this post "[fixed toolbar issue with jquery mobile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13118118/fixed-toolbar-issue-with-jquery-mobile)"

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're running iOS 4 - its support for fixed elements is flaky at best.