# fixed toolbar issue with jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile, toolbar, fixed

I'm working on a PHP interface that will be used in a restaurant inside tablets for taking orders. I'm using jQuery Mobile. To minimize loading times I've created a single page with all the UI and the content part of the page is blank, just the div. When I click on a link I use Ajax to load in the empty content div the pages. I've a fixed header and a fixed footer. The problem is that when I touch or click in a blank area of the loaded pages, header and footer move and go away, header on the top and footer on the bottom of the entire loaded page, and if I click again they return in the right place. This is not happening when I click or touch on  a href link inside the content page.

Can you help me?

Comment: I have the same problem. It can be reproduce on the official [JQM demo page](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/footer-persist-a.html)... Position yourself at the middle of the page and click/touch the screen. The fixed header and footer will disappear. It may be reported bug. I haven't checked yet.
Any workaround would be appreciate!

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9835204/902025).

Just add `data-tap-toggle="false"` to the fixed element.